# Correlation coefficient between two binominals

Tags: probability, statistics

My problem is the following: Roll a dice 30 times, X is the number of 1's and Y is the number of 6's. Find the correlation coefficient $R(X,Y)=\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$. 
The covariance is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0-5*5=-25$ and the product of the ${\sigma}$-s is  $30\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\frac{25}{6}$, that gives $R=-6$ which is a bad solution for $R$. 
Where did I mistake? Can anybody fix it? Thank you for your answers

Comment: Why would $E[XY] = 0$?  The number of $1$s and the number of $6$s can be both positive (and indeed, with $30$ dice, they are likely to be both positive).

Comment: Because In any one trial, if X = 1, then Y = 0 and XY = 0. Similarly, if 
Y = 1, then X = 0 and again XY = 0. In any one trial we can also have 
X = 0, Y = 0, so again XY = 0.

Comment: The way I interpret the question, $X = $ number of $1$s in all $30$ trials, so $0 \le X \le 30$.  After all, you yourself said $E[X] = 5$, which matches my interpretation.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how can i find E(XY)? Are X and Y independent in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $E[XY] \neq 0$

Let $X_i$ be the number of $1$s rolled by the $i$th die; so $X_i = 1$ or $0$, and $X = \sum_{i=1}^{30} X_i$.  Similarly let $Y_i$ be the number of $6$s rolled by the $i$th die.

As you already know, $E[X] = E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i] = 30 \times {1 \over 6} = 5$ and same for $E[Y]$.

Now what is $E[XY]$?  As you pointed out in the comments, it is true that $X_i Y_i = 0$ since one die cannot show both a $1$ and a $6$.  However, $XY \neq \sum_{i=1}^{30} X_i Y_i$!!  And they are certainly dependent (e.g. $X=29 \implies Y \le 1$).

To calculate this, just expand:

$$XY = (\sum X_i) (\sum Y_i) = \sum_i X_i Y_i + \sum_{i \neq j} X_i Y_j$$

This has $30 \times 30 = 900$ terms in it, but you can calculate the expectation of every term easily.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how to calculate E [$\sum_{i \neq j} X_i Y_j$].

Comment: What is $E[X_i Y_j]$?  Note that, when $i \neq j$, they are independent. 
 Think of it this way: $X_i Y_j=1$ if $i$th roll is $1$ and $j$th roll is $6$, otherwise it $=0$.

Comment: Then should I add up $\frac{1}{36}$ 870 times? It gives a too large value for R.

Comment: @vegadam  $\frac{1}{36} \times 870 - 25 = -\frac56$ as the covariance and so $-\frac15$ as the  correlation coefficient, the same as my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you

Answer (score 3):

If you threw one die, then using your method you would get  $\text{Cov}(X,Y)= 0-\frac16 \times \frac16=-\frac1{36}$  and since the variances are each ${\frac{5}{36}}$ the standard deviations are each $\sqrt{\frac{5}{36}}$, and you would get a correlation coefficient of $\frac{-1/36}{5/36}=-\frac15$

For the sums over $30$ independent dice throws, you can immediately say this $-\frac15$ is again the correlation coefficient, but if you prefer a little more explanation, then for the sums over $30$ independent dice throws you multiply the covariance by $30$ to give $\text{Cov}(X,Y)= -\frac{30}{36}=-\frac{5}{6}$ and each of the variances also by $30$ to give ${\frac{150}{36}}={\frac{25}{6}}$ so each standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{25}{6}}$, giving a correlation coefficient of $\frac{-5/6}{25/6}=-\frac15$

Comment: This is interesting...  Why is it true that $Corr(\sum X_i, \sum Y_i) = Corr(X_i, Y_i)$?  Or equivalently, that $Cov(\sum X_i, \sum Y_i) = N \times Cov(X_i, Y_i)$?  Either I'm learning something new here, or I am missing something obvious...  :)

Comment: @antkam $\text{Cov}(\sum_i X_i, \sum_j Y_j) = \sum_i\sum_j\text{Cov}( X_i,  Y_j)$.  But if $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent then $\text{Cov}( X_i,  Y_j)=0$ for $i \not=j$ and $\text{Cov}(\sum_i X_i, \sum_j Y_j) = \sum_i\text{Cov}( X_i,  Y_i)$.  With the same independence you have (a)  if the $(X_i,Y_i)$ are iid then  $\text{Cov}(\sum_i X_i, \sum_j Y_j) = n\, \text{Cov}( X_i,  Y_i)$; (b) if $X_i=Y_i$ then $\text{Var}(\sum_i X_i)=\text{Cov}(\sum_i X_i, \sum_j X_j) =\sum_i\text{Cov}( X_i,  X_i)= \sum_i\text{Var}( X_i)$; and (c) if $X_i$ are iid then  $\text{Var}(\sum_i X_i)=n\,\text{Var}( X_i)$

Comment: +1 oh of course!  the (bi)linearity of covariance.  i should have known that, but this is not a fact i use often so i just forgot.  thanks!  this is a very neat alternate proof!